# Why do we need explicit cursor when implicit cursor already does most of the work in DBMS?

Tags: plsql, database-cursor

I am using sql and pl/sql and most of the time I get work done by implicit cursor itself. Then why do we need explicit cursor?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/why-use-explicit-cursors-instead-of-regular-loops/27047

Comment: Yeah it does. Thanks.